# FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory : react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am getting the error FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory:  in the react.js,
When I am running the **npm run test** but I am able to build and run my project and I am also start to getting the **call retries were exceed issue**  but before I was not getting these issue.

the only change I've made is just separated out the import from each file to a common file.

for more clarification just putting my imports.

I've create an separate import file
**import.js**

```
export {react, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
```

and importing it like this in components
for example using import in **A.js component**

```
import {useState, useEffect} from './import.js'
```

or is there any issue using import like above.

looking for solution how to fix these issue.

**versions:**
node: 12.18.3

Comment: why would you re-export react API ?